# Outputting to a GUI Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, user-interface, azure-active-directory

Hope you can help.

I have the below code that I am running to get a list of the groups an AD user is in.

I have created the GUI as below and I am trying to get the output of the AD command to appear inside the GUI, where I have created a text box.

My two issues are:

1. If you click 'Search', the GUI window closes.
2. If you remove lines to keep the GUI window from closing, it doesn't output anything to the text box.

Any help would be appreciated - really think it is a line of code I am missing! Thanks

````
$testform.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$okb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okb.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(85,130)
$okb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$okb.Text = 'Search'
$okb.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$testform.AcceptButton = $okb
$testform.Controls.Add($okb)
$test.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270,130)
$test.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$test.Text = 'close'
$test.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$testform.AcceptButton = $test
$testform.Controls.Add($test)
$lb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lb.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,40)
$lb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20)
$lb.Text = 'Please enter the username:'
$testform.Controls.Add($lb)
$tb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$tb.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,80)
$tb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20)
$textBoxDisplay = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
$textBoxDisplay.Location = '30, 175'
$textBoxDisplay.Multiline = $true
$textBoxDisplay.Name = "textBoxDisplay"
$textBoxDisplay.Size = '470, 150'
$textBoxDisplay.TabIndex = 1
$testform.Controls.Add($tb)
$testform.Controls.Add($textBoxDisplay)
$testform.Topmost = $true
$testform.Add_Shown({$tb.Select()})
$rs = $testform.ShowDialog()
if ($rs -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
$y = $tb.Text
    $answer = (Get-ADUser $y  -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You may define your function as:

```
$Button_Click = {
    $y = $tb.Text
    $answer = ....
    $textBoxDisplay.Text=$answer
}
```

and assign it to the button click event using `Add_Click(...)`:

```
$okb.Add_Click($Button_Click)
```

and then show the dialog:

```
$testform.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Like the below? As when I run the changes, the window stays open and the output box is empty.    $Button_Click = {
    $y = $tb.Text
    $answer = (Get-ADUser $y  -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name
    $textBoxDisplay.text = $answer
}

$rs = $testform.ShowDialog()
if ($rs -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
 $testform.ShowDialog()
}

Comment: `$Button_Click = { $y = $tb.Text $answer = (Get-ADUser $y -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name $textBoxDisplay.text = $answer } $okb.Add_Click($Button_Click) $testform.ShowDialog()`

Comment: Thank you, that solves the issue of the window closing but it does not output the information into the box on the GUI. It will just come back with ‘OK’

Comment: Have you got any ideas for this?

Comment: Try `$textBoxDisplay.text = $y` and check if the search box text appears into the textbox.